# This arrow function body can be simplified by omitting the curly braces and the keyword 'return'.tslint(arrow-return-shorthand)

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-services

My purpose is read a file json with all name of my input's project

```
{ 'home':'home'}:
```

and  I create the service but I do this:

```
getPropertiesName(): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.get('assets/config/propertiesName.json').pipe(map((response: Response) => {  return response.json(); }));
  }
```

The problem is that the compiler gives me this error:

```
This arrow function body can be simplified by omitting the curly braces and the keyword 'return'.tslint(arrow-return-shorthand)
```

Anyone can help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

adsds it's the same

```
this.http.get(...).pipe(map((response: Response) => {  return response.json(); }));
```

than

```
this.http.get(...).pipe(map((response: Response) => response.json();));
```

BTW, your response is yet a json, has no sense convert to json

Comment: His error is related to his lint configuration, rather than a typescript compiler error

Comment: I had the same error returning an object : map((y) => { return { "something": y }}), in this particular case you need to wrap the object in parenthesis to use the shorthand : map((y) => ({ "something": y }))

Answer (score 0):

This is a lint error from tslint, and is likely auto fixable. Try running:

```
ng lint --fix
```

And then consider the diff in conjunction with the error message you posted.

Comment: Michal i have a question for you. when i write in my project "console.log('..')" i need to use ' '  or the compile give me error if I put double quotes. This problem about what?

Comment: This is another lint rule, you can configure this to your preferences in tslint.json - see docs here for more information https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/